# Issue with redux-toolkit testing

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit, lit

When I'm trying to run tests with using @open-wc/testing library I'm getting an error like below:

[image]

WebComponent which I try to test is written in Lit and connect to redux-toolkit:

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit';

import store from './redux/store/store';
import { connect } from 'pwa-helpers';

export class TestComponent extends connect(store)(LitElement) {


  render() {
    return html`<div>test</div>
    `;
  }
}

customElements.define('test-component', TestComponent);
```

My store file:

```
import { Action, AnyAction, ThunkAction, ThunkDispatch, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { IndicatorSlice } from './features/indicatorSlice.js';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    indicator: IndicatorSlice.reducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;
export const dispatch: ThunkDispatch<RootState, void, AnyAction> = store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

My unit test:

```
import { html } from 'lit';
import { fixture, expect } from '@open-wc/testing';

import type { TestComponent } from '../src/test-component.js';
import '../src/test-component.js';

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let element: TestComponent;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    element = await fixture(html`<test-component></test-component>`);
  });

  it('renders a div', () => {
    const div = element.shadowRoot!.querySelector('div')!;
    expect(div).to.exist;
    expect(div.textContent).to.equal('test');
  });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this error? Where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESM build of `@reduxjs/toolkit` package appears to contain references to `process.env.NODE_ENV` which isn't available in the browser which is why you're getting `ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

You could try replacing those out with a plugin in your web test runner config.

```js
// web-test-runner.config.js
import rollupReplace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import { fromRollup } from '@web/dev-server-rollup';

const replace = fromRollup(rollupReplace);

export default {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    }),
  ],
}
```

See https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/plugins/rollup/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot!